# PHP delete files starting with a specific keyword

Tags: php, apache

I have created a simple cache mechanism through which all dynamic pages will get stored as an html file in the root directory and that html file would be loaded if it exists.

I also wanted to create a mechanism to delete the cache files if a php file is loaded.

I looked around tried somethings but I can't get to delete the files named in the fashion 'cache-*variable*.php'

I want to delete all such files which fall in this pattern in the root directory of the domain. How do I do that? Any tip is most welcome.

Comment: for that you need to enter file path in cache table and when you flush that table files must be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer!

```
<?php array_map('unlink', glob("cache-*.php")); ?>
```

This can be loaded through a password mechanism to effect cache clearing.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php